# Why wont QGIS open?

Tags: qgis

QGIS wont open on my new MAC Mini

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The steps are pretty simple. From the Mac Help Centre:

Go to Security & Privacy. Click the Open Anyway button in the General pane to confirm your intent to open or install the app.
[image]

The warning prompt reappears, and if you're absolutely sure you want to open the app anyway, you can click Open.

[image]

The app is now saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it in the future by double-clicking it, just as you can any authorized app.

These steps apply not only to QGIS but to almost any other app on Mac.

Link to the original article [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491).

Answer (score 1):

From the QGIS download page:

> macOS High Sierra (10.13) or newer is required. QGIS is not yet notarized as required by macOS Catalina (10.15) security rules. On first launch, please control-click on the icon and choose Open from the context menu, after which a confirmation dialog is shown and you need to click the Open button.